# Norm of Complex Vector

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

> Find the norm of $u=(1+7i,2-6i)$.

I managed to simplify the expression to $\sqrt{-80-10j}$, but the answer was $3\sqrt10$. How do I simplify it as such?

Comment: The norm is a real number.

Comment: @user317339 not quite.  The dot product for complex vectors is given by
$$
(u_1,u_2) \cdot (v_1, v_2) = u_1 \overline{v_1} + u_2 \overline{v_2}
$$
hence, $u \cdot u$ is always going to be non-negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The norm of a complex vector is given by
$$
\|(w,z)\| = \sqrt{|w|^2 + |z|^2}
$$
note that we're using $|w|^2$, **not** $w^2$.  So, the calculation becomes
$$
\|(1+7i,2 - 6i)\| = 
\sqrt{|1+7i|^2 + |2 - 6i|^2} = \sqrt{(1^2 + 7^2) + (2^2 + 6^2)} = 3\sqrt{10}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The norm of a complex vector $\vec{a}$ is not $\sqrt{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}}$, but $\sqrt{\overline{\vec{a}} \cdot \vec{a}}$.  So you should get
$$\sqrt{(1-7i)(1+7i)+(2+6i)(2-6i)}$$
$$=\sqrt{90}=3\sqrt{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$||(1+7i,2-6i)||=\sqrt{|1+7i|^2 +|2-6i|^2}=\sqrt{1²+7²+2²+(-6)²}=\sqrt{90}=3\sqrt{10}$$